# Looking for a Detective/Mystery Adventure (D&D)

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-4e, game-recommendation, published-adventures

I have been playing D&D for a month or so now and I have realized that games I enjoy most are the ones that are Detective/Mystery centred. I have played Assassins Knot but it was far too easy and to find the culprit was even easier.

I am in search of a good Detective/Mystery adventure that revolves around questioning, interrogation and searching for clues. I also wish that the adventure be mid-high lvl because part of the reason Assassins Knot was too easy and boring was its low lvl cap. I will be the player of this so I need to send a module to my DM to learn.

If anyone knows the perfect module please tell me and having a link will be even better. Thank You so much.... oh and bonus points if you find one in a oriental setting :)

Comment: Which game are you playing, D&D 4th or 5th edition? You have both tags, did you mean to use them both? (Why?)

Comment: I am using the 5th edition, but my DM has on occasion altered the 4th edition quests to fit the 5th edition